# Is it Possible to see the  execution of each statement in eclipse debug window? +android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, ddms

Is it Possible see the each statement execution in eclipse debug window. Bcoz i'm getting run time error for an android application program but couldn't figure out where exactly the problem by seeing DDMS.Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware of [Java Debugging with Eclipse](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html)?